# Magento Admin Session Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, session, programmatically

I am working on simple php script with email functionality which is depends on admin login in magento admin panel. I use this code for check session of admin in my php file.

> if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn())

But it not provides any thing. Are we able to access magento session outside magento setup or not.I am using php file here.Let me know what i do i need to get session of magento admin outside of magento.

Answer (score 0):

Try this stuff

```
//get the admin session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  //do stuff
}
else
{
  echo "go away bad boy";
}
```

Else try var_dumping the $session variable? Maybe it will help you get on the right track...